# Is there a preexisting function that will return a set of numbers based on a base number and an "offset"?

Tags: c#, algorithm, int

I don't want to reinvent the wheel: If I want to get every integer within a range of N from a given number, what is the most efficient way to do it?

What I mean is something like this:

```
public List<int> getIntsWithinN(int BaseInt, int Offset)
```

...so that if the args passed in were 7 and 3, the result would be 4..10; if the args passed in were 42 and 7, the result would 35..49, etc.

### UPDATE

Okay, I've finally gotten around to trying to implement this. But I don't know if I should pass my List to the ToList() like so:

```
List<int> listInts = new List<int>();
. . .
Enumerable.Range(lineNum - Offset, Offset * 2 + 1).ToList(listInts);
```

...or do it like so:

```
listInts = Enumerable.Range(lineNum - Offset, Offset * 2 + 1).ToList();
```

...but what I need to do is call this several times, so the Intellisense description doesn't seem like what I really need. It says, *"Creates a ... List..."*

But I don't want a new one to be created each time, I want to append to an existing list, and preferably simultaneously disregarding duplicates.

Comment: Why keep the list around in memory at all?  IEnumerable from Enumerable.Range will dynamically generate the values you want each time.  No need to store.  No need to concatenate.  Memory is nearly always more precious than CPU.

Comment: If you have a new question, it's best to post a new question instead of reusing an old one - that way both answerers still get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> preferably simultaneously disregarding duplicates

In that you should consider `HashSet<int>`.

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>();
hashSet.UnionWith(Enumerable.Range(lineNum - offset, offset * 2 + 1));
```

If you want a list, you can call `ToList()` on `hashSet` in the end. You might also want to sort it when converting to list, since `HashSet<T>` keeps the items in an undefined order.

```
var list = hashSet.OrderBy(i=>i).ToList();
```

Answer (score 13):

I don't think there's going to be a function for exactly this, but I think this is the shortest and simplest:

```
Enumerable.Range(BaseInt - Offset, Offset * 2 + 1).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make methods like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> getIntsWithinN(int BaseInt, int Offset)
{
    return getIntsWithinN(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), BaseInt, Offset);
}
public static IEnumerable<int> getIntsWithinN(this IEnumerable<int> source, int BaseInt, int Offset)
{
    return source.Concat(Enumerable.Range(BaseInt - Offset, Offset * 2 + 1));
}
```

Used like this:

```
var myBigList = Extensions.getIntsWithinN(7, 3).getIntsWithinN(42, 7);
```

And then depending on how you want it from there, e.g.

```
var withDupsRemoved = new HashSet<int>(myBigList);
var withDupsRemoved = new HashSet<int>(myBigList).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

If the order of insertion of ranges is important, but you want no duplicates, you could make a list like this:

```
var withDupsRemoved = new List<int>();
foreach (var i in myBigList)
    if (!withDupsRemoved.Contains(i))
        withDupsRemoved.Add(i);
```

If the performance of this becomes an issue, instead of using LINQ's Concat, you can roll your own class that stores the range bounds and when two or more are appended, if there are overlaps, the ranges are adjusted appropriately.